XGBoost __sklearn_tags__ Method Error in Python When Loading Model
I'm getting this error when trying to load a saved XGBRegressor model locally:
FutureWarning: The XGBRegressor or classes from which it inherits use `_get_tags` and `_more_tags`. Please define the `__sklearn_tags__` method, or inherit from `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator` and/or other appropriate mixins such as `sklearn.base.TransformerMixin`, `sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin`, `sklearn.base.RegressorMixin`, and `sklearn.base.OutlierMixin`. From scikit-learn 1.7, not defining `__sklearn_tags__` will raise an error.

I cannot figure this one out at all. I've tried searching and cannot find anybody posting about this problem. I don't get this error when training a model, only when loading a model I've already trained. As far as I can tell, I have the current versions of XGBoost and Scikit-Learn libraries for Python.

just had the same issue. after changing my xgboost and sklearn versions to the one colab uses, it fixed the issue for me. problem arised for me "out of nowhere" a day after adding optuna to the venv.


Scikit-learn version 1.6 modified the API around its "tags", and that's the cause of this error.  XGBoost has made the necessary changes in PR11021, but at present that hasn't made it into a released version.  You can either keep your sklearn version <1.6, or build XGBoost directly from github (or upgrade XGBoost, after a new version is released).
